# Normal Random Variable. $P(4<X<16)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

$P(\frac{4-10}{6} \lt \frac{X-10}{6} \lt \frac{16-10}{6})$

$P(-1 \lt Z \lt 1)$

$(1-\Phi O) - \Phi 0)$

$((\Phi 0)-\Phi 0)$

0,

This can't be correct. I am not sure where I went wrong. This is my first time handling normal random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two steps are good. To compute $$\mathbb{P}(-1<Z<1)$$ we note that this is the same as $$\mathbb{P}(Z<1)-\mathbb{P}(Z<-1) = \Phi(1)-\Phi(-1) = 0.8413-0.1587 = 0.6827.$$

Alternatively, we could note that by symmetry $$\Phi(-1) = 1-\Phi(1),$$
hence $$\mathbb{P}(-1<Z<1) = \Phi(1)-(1-\Phi(1)) = 2\Phi(1)-1 = 1.6827-1 = 0.6827.$$